# JSONDecoder Not Parsing Data

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, decodable

I am trying to get data from this URL

```
https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats
```

I have made a `struct`

```
struct HeroStats : Decodable {
    let localized_name: String
    let primary_attr: String
    let attack_type: String
    let legs: Int
    let image: String
}
```

Top of my View Controller

```
var heros = [HeroStats]()

  func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats")

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error.debugDescription)
                }

                do {

                    guard let data = data else { return}
                    self.heros = try JSONDecoder().decode([HeroStats].self, from: data)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }

                    print(self.heros)
                } catch {
                    print("JSON ERROR")
                    return
                }

            }.resume()
}
```

I always return JSON ERROR for some reason, although everything seems to be correct.

Comment: Don't just print the string "JSON ERROR", print the actual error (`print(error)`) so you can see what the error is

Comment: It is "img" not image in the API response

Comment: The data couldn’t be read because it is missing. - description

Comment: @user9335240 thanks it works! clarification.. even if one of the struct fields is wrong why won't it skip over it and fill in the others?

Comment: If you don't mark the field as optional it will throw an error if it isn't present

Comment: @dan great it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Try to read more on `Codable`/`Encodable` in Swift
[Encoding and Decoding custom types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

You may want to improve your code by making Swift names that differs from JSON names

```
struct HeroStats: Codable {
    let name: String
    let primaryAttribute: String
    let attackType: String // Better to be an enum also
    let legs: Int
    let image: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "localized_name"
        case primaryAttribute = "primary_attr"
        case attackType = "attack_type"
        case legs
        case image = "img"
    }
}
```